# Mtg Combo (Commander): Would it work? Rhys, the Redeemed

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Turn 1 (of combo starting): [Rhys the Redeemed](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRhys%20the%20Redeemed%5d) (Equipped: [Helm of the Host](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHelm%20of%20the%20Host%5d)). Host makes a Rhys copy with haste (at combat so this would be during main phase 2.)
Tap Rhys. Make a second Rhys copy. Tap first copy (with haste.)

Turn 2:
Rhys. 4 Rhys copies from previous turn. Rhys copy this turn.
Tap Rhys. (5 more.) Tap Rhys copy. (10 more.) Tap 2nd Rhys copy. (20 more.) Tap 3rd Rhys copy. (40 more.) Tap 4th Rhys copy. (80 more.) Tap 5th Rhys copy. (160 more.)

•Turn 2 Total: 161 Rhys, the Redeemed. + Any creature tokens already in play.

As for more information I run an elf deck that at the end of a turn playing 5 or more cards I usually have 40 mana left in my mana pool.

Comment: Is there any specific part of this combo that you are unsure about?

Answer (score 2):

The 'combo'<sup>1</sup> will work as you expect. The initial token is created without being legendary and all copies of that will share that feature.

From the Gatherer's rulings on Helm of Hosts:

> The token isn't legendary, and this exception is copiable. If something else copies the token later, that copy also won't be legendary...

---

<sup>1</sup>: Opinion time: I don't think I'd call it a combo on account of it not winning the game on the spot or going infinite and needing elfball-tier mana (a few more cards, like Altar of the Brood, would seal the deal but that's beyond the scope of this question).

Comment: I think you have an unusually narrow definition of what qualifies as a "combo"

Comment: @murgatroid99 Synergy isn't combo to me. You have a load of un-hasty elves after spending 48 mana and your opponent's board is unaffected. Congrats. Kiki Conscripts made a load of hasty zealots that killed the oppoent for 11 mana. That is a combo.

Comment: agreed, this seems less like a combo and more like a cool trick to me. Like Veskah stated, this is 48 mana for a bunch of 1/1's without haste, at the point which you're spending 48 mana you could be Exsanguinating for lethal or whatever the G/W equivalent is. Even casting Entreat the Angels at that point is better because its 22 4/4 Angels with evasion which works out to 88 power. In the strict sense, yes, it may be a combo, but is spending 48 mana to make a bunch of 1/1 elves worth it? No, at that point hardcasting elves is better idea, at least you can get some lords or mana dorks.

Comment: While in almost all circumstances having a Rhys is objectively better than something like Elvish Archdruid. Having a bunch of Rhys's is a different matter. They can be taken out by an Earthquake on X=1. A group of Elf lords is easily much better, they could potentially be large enough to even resist a Blasphemous act. In addition, it makes you an obvious threat and everyone is going to be looking for board wipes. In summary, with 48 mana available you should be winning and not wasting it on this "combo."

Comment: Add Altar of the Brood then you have a combo here haha

Comment: Worth noting that while the "not legendary" modification is copied, the haste is not.

Comment: A further question I have would be whether or not they would have haste. As the text states (on helm of the host): that the copies would have haste.

Comment: @VampieLord look at the comment above you or read the Gatherer page again. The haste is only granted to the Helm copies. Copies made by Rhys will not have it.